# I changed something and I got my old switcher back. How to return a new one?

Tags: eos6

I can't remember what I did .. I need a new, minimalistic switcher (Alt+Tab)

Answer (score 1):

The new Alt + Tab functionality is from Gala. If you can't remember what you did you could always reinstall Gala and that might help. From the terminal:

```
sudo apt reinstall gala
```

Whats going on here:

`sudo` only someone with admin access can directly install/remove/reinstall software. This will ask for your admin password.

`apt` apt is the underlying software that Ubuntu and by extension elementary use for managing system software packages.

`reinstall` This command tells apt that we want to reinstall something thats already on our computer

`gala` The name of the package that we want to reinstall.

So to break it down we are telling the computer: Ask for admin access for the package manager apt, and then in apt we want to reinstall the package gala.

Comment: This is not work